# mocha test - how to call `describe` after `beforeEach` hook

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js

```js
// This is in another file(common)
async function additionalTests(param_test) {
   it("one more test_1",  async() => {

   })

   it("one more test_2",  async() => {

   })
}
describe("Tests", async () => {
   let param_test;
   before(() => {
     console.log("before");
   })

   beforeEach(() => {
     console.log("beforeEach");
     param_test = 20;
   })
   
   describe("Some describe", async () => {
      additionalTests(param_test);
   })
})
```

Problem: `param_test` always gets passed as `undefined` to additionalTests. The reason is: `Some describe`even gets called before `before` and `beforeEach` hook is called.

The one solution I can think of is:

```
describe("Some describe", async () => {
  it("additional", async () => {
    additionalTests(param_test);
   });
})
```

This will work, because until `before` and `beforeEach` hook is called, it won't call `additional` which means `param_test` will be 20. NOTE that I don't like it because I end up having `it` tests(in additionalTests function) inside other `it` test.  Which seems not logical. The closest parent of `it` test should be `describe`. Hope that makes sense.

What would you advice ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend moving the `before` and `beforeEach` functions inside the second nested `describe` like this:

```
describe("Tests", async () => {
   describe("Some describe", async () => {
      let param_test;
      before(() => {
         console.log("before");
      })

      beforeEach(() => {
         console.log("beforeEach");
         param_test = 20;
      })

      additionalTests(param_test);
   })
})
```

I usually use `describe` to group a single method or function beside `it` for every test case.
Hope you have options.

Regards.